# .htaccess: Regular Expression to redirect people to the right language subdirectory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up a redirect that sends people to the right language subdirectory (on a wordpress installation, but that isn't relevant I think):

If the come throught the example.com or example.eu Domain (example.com/cur/...) without any language subdirectory (/en or /de), I want to send them to example.com/cur/en/...

And if they come through the example.de domain, and they don't have any language subdirectory in the url, I want to send them to example.de/cur/de/...

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /cur/

RewriteRule ^http://(www\.)?example\.(eu|com)/cur((?!/en|/de).)*$ http://$1example.$2/cur/en$4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^http://(www\.)?example\.(de)/cur((?!/en|/de).)*$ http://$1example.$2/cur/de$4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cur/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can you see what I'm missing/messing up?

Comment: The `RewriteRule` gets passed a URL-path, not the domain/host name! See fge's answer for further explanation.

Comment: This might be a flaw in my thinking: On the last line RewriteRule . /cur/index.php [L], is the value of the `REQUEST_URI` (that will be read in the index.php) the edited url (with the added /cur/en) or is it the original `REQUEST_URI`?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use mod_rewrite's `%{HTTP_HOSTNAME}`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOSTNAME} ^example\.de$
RewriteRule /(.*) http://example.com/cur/de/$1 [R]
```

etc etc.

But I fail to see why you use .htaccess for that. It is really a job for a `VirtualHost` with `ServerAllias` entries and put your rewrite rules in that vhost, using the same principle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this doesn't quite work yet: If I navigate to example.de/cur/de/... already, than your code would add another layer of /cur/de to the already present url: example.de/cur/de/cur/de/...
Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes I see. In this case, add another RewriteCond right below the first one and before the rule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^/cur/de/`

Comment: And I probably can't use VirtualHost entries since I don't have to the apache config itself. Or are the VirtualHosts defined somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks! Now I set it up as follows:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOSTNAME} ^example\.eu$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cur/de(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cur/en(/|$)
RewriteRule /(.*) http://example.eu/cur/en/$1 [R]`

Unfortunately it doesn't direct me to the /en dir... Am I still missing something?

Comment: This might be a flaw in my thinking: On the last line `RewriteRule . /cur/index.php [L]`, is the value of the REQUEST_URI (that will be read in the index.php) the edited url (with the added /cur/en) or is it the original REQUEST_URI?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.(com|eu)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/cur)?/(en|de)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cur/en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/cur)?/(en|de)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cur/de/$1 [R=301,L]
```